# Behaviour of beast boost Async http client in single threaded asynchronous system when multiple simultaneous requests are sent

Tags: c++, http, boost, single-threaded, beast

How does beast boost async http client works in **c++11** when multiple simultaneous requests are made in a single threaded asynchronous system?

**USE CASE:**

I want to send **multiple simultaneous asynchronous requests** and I am creating **new http client for each request**. When response of any request is received then I am calling a callback function which ***deletes the client after 1 sec of the response received*** to avoid any memory leaks. But it appears that the system/ code hangs in between after some random number of simulatneous http requests even though I create a new client object for each request. Does beast boost use some shared resource as this pause looks like system is in an infinite deadlock. PS: I also tried commenting this delete block but then also system behaves the same.

***Below are the specifications for the boost and compiler version:***

- boost: stable 1.68.0
- BOOST_BEAST_VERSION 181

`clang -v`

```
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

`Thread model: posix`

```
void sendHttpRequest(){
    HttpClient *client = new HttpClient();

    deleteClient = [this,client]{
            int timeout = 1;
        boost::asio::deadline_timer *clientDeleteTimer = new boost::asio::deadline_timer( *this->context);

        clientDeleteTimer->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(timeout));
        clientDeleteTimer->async_wait([client,this,clientDeleteTimer](const boost::system::error_code &ec){
        if(ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted){
             std::cout<<" Operation aborted\n"<<std::flush;           
            return;
        }
        else{
            delete client;
        }
        delete clientDeleteTimer;
   };

   callback = [] {
            std::cout<<"Response recieved successfully\n"<<std::flush;
            deleteClient();
   };

  errback = [] {
           std::cout<<"Response not recieved \n"<<std::flush;
            deleteClient();
   };
   client.sendPostRequest(request, callback , errback);
}
```

this function above is a wrapper function which will be called for each request and internally will create new http async client and delete that client object after 1 sec of response / error is recieved (basically the request has been processed).

Comment: Could you share a bit of your source code for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/1458 .This issue also address the same issue. But i guess still its unresolved.